# Unable to Import Function Name

Tags: python

**BASIC PROBLEM**

I'm getting a name import error, but not in a way that is consistent between two files. I can import names from file A to file B, but not the other way around.

**Update Based on Comments**

I (stupidly) named the file "mix_max.py" instead of "min_max.py". I have changed the file accordingly and updated the GitHub repo. I have also updated the code in my question to reflect that.

**CONTEXT AND CODE**

Rather than reproduce all code here, I made a repo to show what I'm talking about.

I have the following *min_max.py* file:

https://github.com/jeffnyman/tic_tac_toe/blob/master/min_max.py

You can see a line in there to import from tic_tac_toe:

```
from tic_tac_toe import available_moves, apply_move, has_winner
```

That works just fine and I'm able to use those functions in *min_max.py*, such as on lines 74, 84, and 88.

However, I also have the following *tic_tac_toe.py* file:

https://github.com/jeffnyman/tic_tac_toe/blob/master/tic_tac_toe.py

You'll notice a line that does a similar import the other way around:

```
from min_max import min_max_player
```

**PROBLEM**

However when I try to use that (see line 126):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    play_game(random_player, min_max_player, log=True)
```

This does not work. And it does not work because my from/import leads to "cannot import name min_max_player" when I try to run tic_tac_toe.py.

**Workaround 1**

I found I can fix this by changing my import to this:

```
import min_max
```

And then changing the code like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    play_game(random_player, min_max.min_max_player, log=True)
```

The key change there being `min_max.min_max_player`.

What I don't see is why this is necessary, particularly since I didn't have to do this when importing *from* tic_tac_toe.py *to* min_max.py.

**Workaround 2**

I can apparently defer the import like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from min_max import min_max_player
    play_game(random_player, min_max_player, log=True)
```

That works.

I'm coming to Python from a Ruby and Java context so I fear I'm missing something terribly obvious here. So maybe those things I list as "workarounds" are, in fact, the actual solution?

Comment: Welcome to Python, that is very likely to be a circular import you are trying to achieve, also a symptom for coupling. Good luck!

Comment: is it mix_max or min_max , check your import statements in question and update

Comment: @Stack Good point! I misnamed the file `mix_max.py` (embarrassing). I will update the question. So the import, which is calling "mix_max" was correct, as far as it was, however, I have updated the code to use the correct file name. So the same error still applies.

Comment: ok, I will try my best to explain what is happening: 

So when you run **tic_tac_toe.py**, it tries to import min_max_player from min_max. In doing so, it will try to load min_max.py, but the first line in min_max.py actually imports from tic_tac_toe.py , i.e `from tic_tac_toe import available_moves, apply_move, has_winner` , so, now it tries to import those functions from tic_tac_toe which is still loading from min_max and gives you the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the help of Stack and hurturk, who both pointed me in the right direction (see their comments), it looks like the concept I was missing and/or not seeing was the circular reference as well as perhaps the race condition therefrom.

So I believe one answer to my question are the workarounds that I posted in the original question.

Workaround 2 is to essentially to defer the import, as such:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from min_max import min_max_player
    play_game(random_player, min_max_player, log=True)
```

I do find it perhaps odd that this doesn't lead to the same issue since the "defer" isn't really all that deferred; given that I handle this in the very first lines of `tic_tac_toe.py` that get executed.

I'm honestly not sure why either workaround is the answer necessarily, but they do have the benefit of working. It seems that it's just a matter of what kind of expression I have in place.

I like the Workaround 2 one because it allows me to use "min_max_player" similar to how I call "random_player". Workaround 1 forces me to use "random_player" and "min_max.min_max_player".